# Numpy.unique(): How to get an ordered "inverse index" efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I would like to get an *ordered* inverse value from `numpy.unique(return_inverse=True)`, which normally returns an (unordered) inverse, as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2, 2, 3, 1])
arr_unq, arr_inv = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)

print(arr_inv)

# output: [1 1 2 0]
```

Notice that the inverse index is not ordered.
In contrast, I like to get an ordered inverse, like below:

```py
# output: [0 0 1 2]
```

If relevant, you may consider the total number of elements to be around 100k, and number of unique elements to be around 10k.

Answer (score 0):

To recompute an ordered *reverse* index, we can create a mapper as follows:

```py
arr_unq, arr_ind, arr_inv = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True, return_index=True)
mapper = np.zeros(len(arr_ind), dtype=int)
mapper[np.argsort(arr_ind)] = np.arange(len(arr_ind))
print(mapper[arr_inv])

# output: [0 0 1 2]
```

I wonder if a more efficient approach exists?

Comment: There is a simpler (but not necessarily faster) way to create `mapper`: `arr_ind.argsort().argsort()`

Comment: Very good @MechanicPig, so the calculation becomes a oneliner: `arr_ind.argsort().argsort()[arr_inv]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good job for [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) (which, despite being a pandas method returns an array), and is faster than `numpy.unique` for large datasets:

```
import pandas as pd

idx, values = pd.factorize(arr)

print(idx)
```

Output: `array([0, 0, 1, 2])`